# I cannot get Remix in any browser or desktop to load...any ideas?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

I have disabled mixed content, my DNS, my VPN, etc and in any browser it shows up blank but has the warning at the bottom "You are using an `https` connection. Please switch to `http` if you are using Remix against an `http Web3 provider` or allow Mixed Content in your browser."  I tried http only, etc and nothing.  It also happens in the desktop IDE.  Ideas/help? Thanks!

Comment: What is the URL of the HTTP provider that you're using? Redact any sensitive data such as an API key if it's part of the URL.

Comment: After going to remix.ethereum.org the url loads this : https://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.1+commit.df193b15.js.  I replace https with http and same result.  In Brave, all shields are down and allow insecure content is on.  In FF, protections are off.  I even loaded a new profile in FF with zero extensions and "security.mixed_content.block_active_content" is false and same result.

Comment: I got the info message "You are using a `https` connection" when opening the browser https version of Remix (https://remix.ethereum.org/). But the IDE (both browser and desktop) load fine on my end. Possibly a firewall blocking your connection?

Comment: I have the Windows built in firewall...any way to look at the logs or figure out if it's blocking it?

Answer (score 0):

Due to system config It will take some time. So just wait for a minute It will get loaded. For me also this occurs, I just waited for a minute after that website opened.

Comment: For me its Minimum of 3-4 min

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on the Browser you are using.
I've been using Brave for some time, and they provide great built-in security features(e.g. HTTPS Everywhere).
I can disable the HTTPS upgrade with a few clicks and connect to my local RPC Server.
[How to disable forced transfer from http to https I'm Brave Browser?](https://community.brave.com/t/how-to-disable-forced-transfer-from-http-to-https/260310)